How i can find the optimal blend order that can minimize lead time in excel using VBA
i need to find the optimal solution of blend order in production scheduling problem, so that lead time between every blend can be minimized. how to do that in excel vba?. i already have cycle time data for every blend and calculate start time & end time for every single process
i try to make a vba code to iterate every blend order possibility, but end up have to wait so long when i run the macro and just showing not responding message
Sub MinimizeLeadTime()
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    Application.Calculation = xlCalculationManual
    Application.EnableEvents = False
    
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Trial")
    
    Dim iterSheet As Worksheet
    Set iterSheet = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Iteration")
    
    Dim blendRange As Range
    Set blendRange = ws.Range("C5:C26")
    
    Dim perm As Object
    Set perm = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")
    
    Dim blends() As String
    Dim totalLeadTime As Double
    Dim bestLeadTime As Double
    Dim bestOrder As Variant
    Dim order As Variant
    Dim i As Integer, j As Integer
    Dim resultRow As Integer
    Dim count As Long
    Dim startTime As Double
    
    startTime = Timer
    
    iterSheet.Cells.Clear
    iterSheet.Cells(1, 1).Value = "Best Blend Order"
    iterSheet.Cells(1, 2).Value = "Minimum Total Lead Time (minutes)"
    resultRow = 2
    
    ReDim blends(1 To blendRange.Rows.count)
    For i = 1 To blendRange.Rows.count
        blends(i) = ws.Cells(i + 1, 3).Value
    Next i
    
    Call Permutations(blends, LBound(blends), UBound(blends), perm)
    
    bestLeadTime = 999999999
    count = 0
    
    For Each order In perm.Items
        count = count + 1
        If count > 10000 Then Exit For
        
        totalLeadTime = 0
        For j = LBound(order) To UBound(order) - 1
            Dim endTimeMixing As Date, startTimeMixing As Date
            
            endTimeMixing = ws.Cells(Application.Match(order(j), blendRange, 0) + 1, 40).Value
            startTimeMixing = ws.Cells(Application.Match(order(j + 1), blendRange, 0) + 1, 39).Value
            
            totalLeadTime = totalLeadTime + (startTimeMixing - endTimeMixing) * 24 * 60
        Next j
        
        If totalLeadTime < bestLeadTime Then
            bestLeadTime = totalLeadTime
            bestOrder = order
        End If
    Next order
    
    iterSheet.Cells(resultRow, 1).Value = Join(bestOrder, ", ")
    iterSheet.Cells(resultRow, 2).Value = bestLeadTime
    
    MsgBox "Best Blend Order: " & Join(bestOrder, ", ") & vbCrLf & "Minimum Lead Time: " & bestLeadTime & " minutes"
    MsgBox "Total time: " & Format(Timer - startTime, "0.00 seconds")
    
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
    Application.Calculation = xlCalculationAutomatic
    Application.EnableEvents = True
End Sub

Sub Permutations(arr As Variant, l As Long, r As Long, ByRef perm As Object)
    Dim i As Long
    If l = r Then
        perm.Add perm.count, arr
    Else
        For i = l To r
            Call Swap(arr(l), arr(i))
            Call Permutations(arr, l + 1, r, perm)
            Call Swap(arr(l), arr(i)) 'backtrack
        Next i
    End If
End Sub

Sub Swap(a As Variant, b As Variant)
    Dim temp As Variant
    temp = a
    a = b
    b = temp
End Sub


The number of permutations for 21 out of 21 items is 51,090,942,171,709,440,000 if that's related to what you're trying to figure out.

To put that number in perspective, if you were to run it on a 60 gigaflop GPU and it took only one operation to solve one permutation, it would only take 2332919 years to run your program.
